# Calualte the model coefficients using maximum likelihood estimator for non-linear curve

Tags: python-3.x, weibull, log-likelihood, exponential-distribution

I have a non-linear dataset that follows a certain distribution as such:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


## Define the curve 
def curve(t,α,ξ,β1,β2):  

   ## Model parameters: (α, ξ, β1, β2)
   
   ## Covariate-1 of exponential distribution
   X1 = np.exp(t/20) 

   ## Covariate-2 of exponential distribution
   X2 = np.exp(t/10) 

   ## 2-parameter Weibull distribution
   ho = (α/ξ) * (t/ξ)**(α-1) 

   ## Data 
   h = ho * np.exp(β1*X1 + β2*X2)
   
   return h

## Time axis
T = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)

## Generate the data
H = curve(T, α = 2.3 ,ξ = 4.8e-4, β1 = 1.1, β2 = 2.1)


## Plot the data
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 7.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
plt.plot(T, H, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Now let's say, given the data (T, H), that looks as such:
[image]

how do I back-calculate the Model parameters(α, ξ, β1, β2) by using the maximum likelihood estimator?

Can somebody please help me out with this.

Comment: This is not a density function. How can you use `MLE`? your function seems to be non-decreasing in nature. You should consider having bounds or introducing some constraints. For example, it is obvious that α >1 and ξ > 0. Consider using [`NLS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares)

Comment: HI @NLS ...I am a bit confused here. Why can we not use MLE for a dataset that is a combination of Weibull and exponential distribution?

Comment: for MLE, you need data generated/presumed to be generated from a given distribution and by a certain theta. We then need to estimate the theta from the data. In your case, you have the unnormalized density function and not the data. In your case you need to use `NLS` and not `MLE`